# if I have 100k data in json and I want to use it in multiselect in flutter app how would I do using search only

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android, flutter-dropdownbutton, flutter-datatable

if I have 100k data in json and I want to use it in multiselect in flutter app how would I do using search only?

```
[
  {
     "id": 16905,
     "name": "5-HTP"
    },
    {
     "id": 16906,
     "name": "5-hydroxytryptophan"
    },
    {
     "id": 16907,
     "name": "60 Second Fluoride Gel"
    },
    {
     "id": 16908,
     "name": "60-Second Fluoride Foam"
    },
    {
     "id": 16909,
     "name": "7T Gummy ES Chewable Tablets"
    },
    {
     "id": 16910,
     "name": "8 in 1 Ultra Care"
    },
]
```

Comment: I want to use it efficiently without any future delay or don't want to load data at once.

Comment: Could you please better explain your question.
And bare searching through this much data linearly will be lot slow, it will lead to getting your app freeze while you are searching through json dict

Comment: Are you accessing data from firebase?

Comment: No I have stored it in assets folder , till now my data is 20k which makes it slow to load but somehow I managed by adding loader for that but in future if I need to load 1 Lakh data or more than that then It would be difficult for me to implement the same.

Comment: No, that's not right way to store and fetch data.
That's will freeze your app for sure.
You will have to store data in some other cloud source.
Reffer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873000/how-can-i-access-json-object-using-flutter

Comment: @AnonymousAtom If I fetch data this way then I wanted to ask is there any multi select which fetches the data into the list only when searched not all at once ?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood.

Comment: thanks will take care of that.